# Routing based on role - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
Rails 3.2
```

I have 2 sets of controllers, one for admin and one for regular users.

When an admin logs in, I want them to go to the index method, in controllers/admin/tickets_contoller.rb

I have the following in my routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  root to: 'tickets#index'
  ....
```

and in my application_controller.rb, I have:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
  if current_user && current_user.current_company
    view_context.can? :index, :admin
      admin_root_path
  end
end
```

But, when I log in as admin, it seems to be going to the standard tickets_controller, not the admin/tickets_controller

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does your rake routes look like?

Comment: admin_root        /admin(.:format)         admin/tickets#index